# Multiple traces for single connection in Eagle

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, routing

I'm manually routing a power distribution network in Eagle, and am trying to follow the IC vendor's recommendation to attach vias to the power plane both left and right of the bypass capacitor's connection pad.

As soon as I've made a single connection, Eagle believes that to be sufficient, which means I cannot use the "Route" tool to create the second trace and via. Manually drawing a trace, placing a via and renaming everything to the network name works, but is there a shorter and/or easier way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found it!

Ctrl-Click on an existing trace or pad starts a new trace.

Answer (score -2):

The way I do it is as follows:

1. Switch to Copy mode
2. Copy a segment of the signal and move it over
3. Adjust both ends of that segment to your liking

---

Edit: You can copy vias around just as easily.